# Software for easy spherical coordinate plotting from data file

Tags: python, plotting, software-recommendation

Does anyone have any suggestions for good open source plotting software which has good graphical spherical coordinate plotting (from a data file). I have a three column data file where column 1 is $\theta$, column 2 is $\phi$ and column three is $f(\theta, \phi)$. I would like to plot this in spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi, \rho = f(\theta, \phi))$, where points of equal $\rho$ are represented by equivalent colours. Does anyone have any recommendations regarding this type of plotting?

Also, is it possible to easily represent the plot with different colours as a function of the spherical coordinate $\rho$ (hence distance from the origin)?

By the way I used Python to produce these data files.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to convert the spherical coordinates to Cartesian and use a 3D scatter plot in Python using mplot3D+pyplot. If you want an interpolated surface plot, you might want to look at this question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816537/spherical-coordinates-plot-in-matplotlib